# Can't archive any more in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios, xcode4, archive

Same problem as here ([Can't archive anymore, yet "build for archive" still works (Xcode 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722414/cant-archive-anymore-yet-build-for-archive-still-works-xcode-4)).  However, the fixes suggested didn't work.  I don't know why.  Here are the steps I went through:

1. Built and archived for a Distribution provisioning profile.
2. Archived, and shared the app.
3. Added another device to the profile, downloaded and imported into Xcode.
4. Rebuilt the code - it gave me an error that my bundle identifier was wrong, so I fixed it.
5. Built for Archiving - no errors.
6. Archived - failed with no errors.

I would also add, it runs fine in the simulator, but no longer builds and runs for an attached device.  The build says Failed, No Issues.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got it!  After trying all kinds of things throughout forums, I was answering a related question in the Apple Developer Forum, and that forced me to go back and look at my Entitlements.plist file.  For some reason it was empty.  I deleted and recreated it, set my allow debugging to NO, and it built just fine.

Don't know why Entitlements got wiped, but hopefully that saves others the hair-pulling I just went through!