# Xcode 4.2: Build for Archive is good, but Archive fails with errors

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, archive

I am trying to build my app and submit it to the App Store but Xcode keeps giving me errors when trying to do that.

When I build and run in the simulator it works, when I build and run for a device it works, when I try to use the build for archive option it works, when I actually try to archive it it will fail with 9 or 11 errors depending on (IMHO) what time of day it is.

Anyone have any idea why? I tried following [some other tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722414/cant-archive-anymore-yet-build-for-archive-still-works-xcode-4) such as deleting the project folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

And another user said to clean the build folder but that option is grayed out in the menu bar. 
Anyone know of any other solutions?

All my errors are file not found errors, I am using Three20 so the errors are:

```
'Three20Core/TTCorePreprocessorMacros.h' file not found
'Three20Core/TTDebug.h' file not found
'Three20Core/TTCorePreprocessorMacros.h' file not found
'Three20Core/TTGlobalCore.h' file not found

../scripts/Protect.command: line 23: cd: /Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TTCatalog-gcnbfpwscygfrmdhcfiahsatpdba/ArchiveIntermediates/pr/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/../three20/Three20Network: No such file or directory

'Three20UICommon/private/UIViewControllerGarbageCollection.h' file not found
'Three20Core/TTGlobalCoreLocale.h' file not found
'Three20UICommon/private/UIViewControllerGarbageCollection.h' file not found

../scripts/Protect.command: line 23: cd: /Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TTCatalog-gcnbfpwscygfrmdhcfiahsatpdba/ArchiveIntermediates/pr/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/../three20/Three20UICommon: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @XenElement No, clean build folder is, http://cl.ly/3V0l1v440C2E3Z0I132E

Comment: Seeing this problem also!  Also using three20.  Deleted my entire derivededData but still won't compile!

Comment: I have the same issue. did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be path issue in environment variables.

Just carefully follow the steps mentioned in integrating Three20 library @ https://github.com/facebook/three20
( use The Second option to add it to your project manually)

Make sure the configuration added to All Configuration (Debug, Release, Distribution(if exists).

Also Make sure your Xcode preference are as below
xcode->preferences->locations

1. Select Derived Data->relative
2. Select Advanced -> Legacy

Comment: I made this changes and got following error: 'Three20/Three20.h' file not found

Comment: where is the header files Three20.h getting copied after build?